# Hadoop error 216 during installation

Tags: hadoop, sdk

I am trying to install hadoop.

When using the Sdk command prompt to do the following command:

```
mvn package -Pdsit,native-win -DskipTests -Dtar
```

i got the following error:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-antrun-plugin:1.6:
run (pre-dist) on project hadoop-project-dist: An Ant BuildException has occured:
Execute failed: java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "sh" (in directory "C:
\hadoop-2.2.0-src\hadoop-project-dist\target"): CreateProcess error=216, This 
version of %1 is not compatible with the version of Windows you're running. Check
your computer's system information to see whether you need a x86 (32-bit) or x64
(64-bit) version of the program, and then contact the software publisher -> [Help 1]
```

Comment: I assume you're trying to install it on windows. Did you check that link ? http://www.srccodes.com/p/article/38/build-install-configure-run-apache-hadoop-2.2.0-microsoft-windows-os

Comment: Right i am installing on windows and i'm following that link. I solved the problem: it was a mapping issue with the hard drive.
Thank you

Comment: I have the same issue how to solve it??